# Auto Increment column value is larger than I expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

When I put data in DB with python,
I met a problem that auto increment column value is larger than I expected.

Assume that I use the following function multiple times to put data into the DB.
'db_engine' is a DB, which contains table 'tbl_student' and 'tbl_score'.
To manage the total number of student, table 'tbl_student' has Auto increment column named 'index'.

```
def save_in_db(db_engine, dataframe):
    # tbl_student
    student_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
        "ID":dataframe['ID'],
        "NAME":dataframe['NAME'],
        "GRADE":dataframe['GRADE'],
        })
    student_dataframe.to_sql(name="tbl_student",con=db_engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

    # tbl_score
    score_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
        "SCORE_MATH": dataframe['SCORE_MATH'],
        "SCORE_SCIENCE":dataframe['SCORE_SCIENCE'],
        "SCORE_HISTORY":dataframe['SCORE_HISTORY'],
    })
    score_dataframe.to_sql(name="tbl_score",con=db_engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

'tbl_student' after some inputs is as follows:

| index | ID | NAME | GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023001 | Amy | 1 |
| 1 | 2023002 | Brady | 1 |
| 2 | 2023003 | Caley | 4 |
| 6 | 2023004 | Dee | 2 |
| 7 | 2023005 | Emma | 2 |
| 8 | 2023006 | Favian | 3 |
| 12 | 2023007 | Grace | 3 |
| 13 | 2023008 | Harry | 3 |
| 14 | 2023009 | Ian | 3 |

Please take a look column 'index'.
When I put in several times, 'index' has larger value than I expected.

What should I try to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not a problem.  An "autoincrement" column just means there won't be any duplicates.  No one guarantees the sequence will be unbroken, and it shouldn't affect your processing in any way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try find other way!!

Comment: Other way to do what?  Why do you care if the IDs are not continuous?  You can certainly have pandas do an index, but it won't match the keys in the database.

Comment: I thouhght that the total number of student could be known only through the index until just now. Now I know it is as same as the length of the dataframe. It took me a while to realize that it wasn't something to consider T.T Your comment have been great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
student_dataframe.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem situation is 'index' part connected to another table as a FOREIGN KEY.
Every time I add a data, the error occurred because there was no key(because the index value is not continuous!).

I solve this problem by checking the index part once before put data in DB and setting it as key.
Following code is what I tried.

```
index_no = get_index(db_engine)
dataframe.index = dataframe.index + index_no + 1 - len(dataframe)
dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

If anyone has the same problem, it could be nice way to try another way rather than trying to make auto increment key sequential.